# How to check the details are correct or not without rendering the page in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a registration form using django framework and in  the phone number content how can I check the number is only equal to 10 digits without rendering the page, because  when i render the page if the phone number condition is wrong whole input's will  be deleted and return the page how can i handle that without deleting the data??

i have explained as above

Comment: You would have to do it in Javascript, in the browser.  You'd add an `onSubmit` handler to your `<form>`, and validate the fields.  The `onSuibmit` handler decides whether to allow the submission to proceed or not.

Answer (score 0):

To validate a phone number field in a Django form without losing the other input data when the page is re-rendered, you can use Django's form validation system. Overriding the `clean_<fieldname>()` method in your form class to add custom validation for the phone number field ensures that if the validation fails, Django will return the form with the entered data and appropriate error messages, without losing the data in other fields.

First, define a form class for your registration form. Assume you have a field named phone_number. Here's how you can define the form:

```
from django import forms

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    # ... other fields ...
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

def clean_phone_number(self):
    phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
    if len(phone_number) != 10 or not phone_number.isdigit():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Phone number must be 10 digits.")
    return phone_number
```

In the clean_phone_number method, we're checking if the phone number is exactly 10 digits. If it's not, a ValidationError is raised.

In your view, handle this form normally. When the form is submitted, Django will automatically call the clean_phone_number method and perform the validation.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RegistrationForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process the data
            return redirect('success_url')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'registration_form.html', {'form': form})
```

If the validation fails, Django will add an error to the form, and the `form.is_valid()` check will fail. The same form instance is then rendered again, preserving the user's input.

In your template, ensure to display the form fields and any associated error messages.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {{ form.phone_number.errors }}
    {{ form.phone_number }}
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

This setup ensures that if there's an error with the phone number, the error message will be displayed next to the phone number field, and other fields will retain their values.

**Using Django's form validation system in this way allows you to validate individual fields without losing the data entered in other fields of the form when the page is re-rendered.**